# How can I distiguish string from formula when reading excel cells with apache poi?

Tags: apache-poi

I have read http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html but I dont get it to work ...

I have a column in my sheet that contains these values:

```
D+1           (pseudo-formula, to be evaluated in java)
01.01.0001    (string constant)
=A1           (formula where A1 contains pseudo formula 'D+2')
=A2           (formula where A2 contains '13.08.2013')
```

(For strings like "D+1" I have written a parser that replaces D by todays date and increments it by one. "01.01.0001" is a magic value. "=A3" is obviously an excel formula )

**How can I safely get all these values to a plain old java string that**

- **dereferences excel formulas before**
- **leaves pseudo formulas intact**
- **treats everything else as string**

**???**

so for above example I want to get:

```
"D+1"
"01.01.0001"
"D+2"
"13.08.2013"
```

Comment: Just read the article about formular evaluation again. It is offtopic imho. I only read the file so i can use the cached results. No need for evaluation....

Comment: When i switch for cell.type and find type=formula, can i do cell.getStringContents(). ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing it by hand: You need to check both [getCellType()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellType()) and [getCachedFormulaResultType()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCachedFormulaResultType%28%29). The type will let you work out what kind of cell it is, for formatting / cell value fetching etc. For formulas, when you see it's a formula cell, you can then fetch the last evaluated value and the type of that

However, based on what you want, I think there might be a much simpler way to go. I think you can probably use [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html), specifically [formatCellValue(Cell)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29)

If you use DataFormatter, it'll identify the type (including formulas), fetch the value, fetch the Excel-applied number/date formatting rules, and apply those. You get back a String which is the closest Apache POI can manage to what's shown in Excel, which looks like what you want

Comment: Looks promising. Esp. the tip with dataformatter. Thanks!

Comment: A worryingly large proportion of the Apache POI questions on Stackoverflow boil down to "stop trying that and just use DataFormatter" !

Comment: So thats how one gets many points in SO. One good answer to many dumb questions.. :-)